# Webcam image does not show full size

Tags: html, css

I try to stream my webcam, i want to get it in full width inside the div.
Somehow it's not working for me. I try to use `%` to make it responsive possible.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gyevxcm/)

---

HTML

```
<div id="webcam">
    <div class="webcam-stream">
        <video src="blob:http://localhost/e814ab72-c414-4d97-9eca-b205c914fd6b" controls="" id="ME55u8ZS83mhoMloE2AE5OU9LrkDZdasaEfsKMO"></video>
    </div>
</div>


<h3>
    END RESULT
</h3>
<img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HPj7kAyuy.png">
```

---

CSS

```
#webcam {
    height: 35%;
    width: 40%;
}
.webcam-stream {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What's the aspect ratio of your video? Like is it 4:3, 16:9, etc?

Comment: @MichaelCoker i don't know what the aspect is. But what i want is that the black image must be equals to the parent div. If you see the controls takes the correct width but not the image inside.

Comment: Try the CSS here - https://jsfiddle.net/2gyevxcm/1/

Comment: @MichaelCoker as you see in the prntscr it floats out of the parent div I hightlighted the div https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HPLCl1lQU.png

Comment: Find out what the aspect ratio is. You need to know that to create a full screen, responsive video. If you tell me what it is, I can come up with a solution for you. Otherwise, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

in any case for responsive it should have bakground, for all screens all devices, or you will have distortion of video in full size mode.
or please read articles, and try to make
https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

there is few way
1) make fixed container for wrapper, with top,left,bottom,right set to zero, and than for it child add absolute.
2) try with 100vw and 100vh, this can not work in some IE, and older browsers

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question 100% but to make it easier for you to see which styles need to change add different background colors to your views.

```
#webcam {
    height: 35%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
}
.webcam-stream {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

In this following example a changed the % values of the child elements to be 10% less to show you what I mean.

[image]

Comment: As you see now on the prntscr i want black equals and green eqauls red https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HPVPIhtsY.png (black is the video image)